# Deserialize Map<String, List<?>> using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I serialize data in server:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, List<?>> resultMap = BackendUpdateManager.getInstance()
    .getUpdates(timeHolder, shopIdInt, buyerIdInt);
gson.toJson(resultMap);
```

and deserialize:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, List<?>> resultMap =  gson.fromJson(json,
    new TypeToken<Map<String, List<?>>>() {
    }.getType());
```

However, when I try use items from the `Map`:

```
List<ProductCategory> productCategoryList = (List<ProductCategory>)updateMap.get(key);

for(ProductCategory productCategory : productCategoryList) {

}
```

I get error:

> Caused by: `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` cannot be cast to `com.example.model.entity.ProductCategory`

How can I fix this error or otherwise create a  `Map` with `List<different classes>`?

I've tried creating classes with getters and setters, that contains `List`s of different classes instead of `Map<String, List<?>>` and use it for serialization and deserialization. But I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: If you know it's a `Map<String, List<ProductCategory>>`, why did you deserialize it as a `Map<String, List<?>>`?

Comment: @azurefrog It is not only List<ProductCategory>. Different keys different types: `updateMap.get(key)`

Comment: As the error points: when you deserialize with ? GSON and also JACKSON use some kind of map to deserialize the string and you need to do the mapping by yourself.

Comment: @igreen when I try use objects from List<?> after deserialize. This error happens when is incorrect deserialization
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356140/how-can-i-use-google-gson-to-deserialize-a-json-array-into-a-a-collection-of-a-g

Answer (score 2):

How is Gson supposed to know that a particular Json string is a `ProductCategory`? For instance, if the definition of `ProductCategory` is this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.vitvetal;  

public class ProductCategory {
    String name;
    String type;
}
```

And the Json is this:

```
{
    "name":"bananas",
    "type":"go-go"
}
```

Where is the link that tells Gson to create an instance of a `com.stackoverflow.vitvetal.ProductCategory`?

### This link doesn't exist, because you didn't tell Gson about it.

So what gson does instead is, it creates a `Map<String, String>` that looks like

```
"name" -> "bananas"
"type" -> "go-go"
```

If you want to do something different, the *easiest* thing to do - but also the least powerful - is to fully specify the parameterized type when you create your `TypeToken`; no wildcard `<?>` allowed.

If you need to do something more powerful, like creating maps with more variety in objects, you need to create a **custom deserializer**, using a [`TypeAdapter<T>`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html), that teaches Gson how to handle your particular sort of object.

- [Here is a tutorial on how to do write gson TypeAdapters](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-type-adapter.jsp)